# Typescript eslint tsconfig resolution error in monorepo

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, monorepo, typescript-eslint

I have the following project structure:

```
/root
  /serviceA 
  /serviceB
  /serviceC 
  /serviceD
```

Not all of the services are typescript / node based, so I want to avoid adding tsconfig into the root. Each service is setup as a complete unit with its own installation of eslint, ts, and own configuration.

Any `ts` service I open VScode shows the following error:

```
Parsing error: Cannot read file '/users/{me}/dev/{root}/tsconfig.json'.
```

This is correct, as there is no such file, so how do I force vscode & eslint to use the individual services configuration files?

Answer (score 15):

Edit your `.eslintrc` file with:

```js
module.exports = {
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.json',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },
};
```

Source: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/251#issuecomment-488538828

Comment: I already have this and it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

In `.eslintrc` you can set the path to `tsconfig.json`.

```
parserOptions : {
  project: './tsconfig.json',
},
```

Here’s an example where it is just set for ts files

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/eslint-config-auto/blob/master/rules/%40typescript-eslint/parser.js

Comment: Sorry about the very long delay, but I already have this in each ES lint config file.